# Write boolean dataframe to csv with 1s and 0s

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with boolean values, i.e.

```
    col1   col2
1   True   False
2   False  True
3   True   True
```

when I use pandas' `DataFrame.to_csv` method, the resulting dataframe looks like

```
,col1,col2
1,True,False
2,False,True
3,True,True
```

is there a way to write the boolean variables as 1s and 0s (more space-efficient), i.e.

```
,col1,col2
1,1,0
2,0,1
3,1,1
```

without having to cast the entire dataframe first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's quite simple actually, just multiply the df by 1.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """
    col1   col2
1   True   False
2   False  True
3   True   True
    """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+')

print(df*1)
```

This will change it to:

```
   col1  col2
1     1     0
2     0     1
3     1     1
```

From there you can either reassign the df from within the code by doing `df = df*1` or `df2 = df*1`. The first will prevent duplicate copy.

Comment: This is nice because it also leaves strings as they were.

Answer (score 8):

You can just convert the `dtype` of the df to `int` this will convert `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`:

```
In [16]:
df.astype(int)

Out[16]:
   col1  col2
1     1     0
2     0     1
3     1     1
```

Comment: I prefer this solution over @Leb 's solution, it is much more explicit.