# Data Cleaning with Pandas in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean a csv file for data analysis. How do I convert TRUE FALSE into 1 and 0?

When I search Google, they suggested `df.somecolumn=df.somecolumn.astype(int)`. However this csv file has 100 columns and not every column is true false(some are categorical, some are numerical). How do I do a sweeping code that allows us to convert any column with TRUE FALSE to 1 and 0 without typing 50 lines of `df.somecolumn=df.somecolumn.astype(int)`

Comment: Perhaps a different question - why do you need to cast a Boolean to an Int? In nearly all use cases, the two can be achieve equivalent results. If you want them as integers so you can count the number of trues, then Pandas can already do this with Booleans.

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601010/write-boolean-dataframe-to-csv-with-1s-and-0s

Comment: I don't this is a dup. The question is very different. Though ```df*1``` might work as it does not affect string and numeric values.

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

`df.select_dtypes(include='bool')=df.select_dtypes(include='bool').astype(int)`

Comment: Could be rewritten as `df.update(df.select_dtypes('bool').astype(int))`...

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach. 
First, dtypes of a dataframe can be returned using `df.dtypes`, which gives a pandas series that looks like this,

```
a     int64
b      bool
c    object
dtype: object
```

Second, we could replace `bool` with int type using `replace`,

`df.dtypes.replace('bool', 'int8')`, this gives

```
a     int64
b     int8
c    object
dtype: object
```

Finally, pandas seires is essentially a dictionary which can be passed to `pd.DataFrame.astype`.

We could write it as a oneliner,

```
df.astype(df.dtypes.replace('bool', 'int8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
df.somecolumn = df.somecolumn.apply(lambda x: 1 if x=="TRUE" else 0)
```

If you want to iterate through all your columns and check wether they have TRUE/FALSE values, you can do this:

```
for c in df:
    if 'TRUE' in df[c] or 'FALSE' in df[c]:
        df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='TRUE' else 0)
```

Note that this approach is case-sensitive and won't work well if in the column the TRUE/FALSE values are mixed with others.